# Scala error: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class scala.Some

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am trying to get count of mongo query result, but I am getting error
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class scala.Some. Can somebody help?

This is my code:

```
def fetchData() = {
    val mongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1")
    val database = mongoClient.getDatabase("assignment")
    val movieCollection = database.getCollection("movies")
    val ratingCollection = database.getCollection("ratings")
    val latch1 = new CountDownLatch(1)
    movieCollection.find().subscribe(new Observer[Document] {

      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = {
        println("Error while fetching data")
        e.printStackTrace()
      }

      override def onComplete(): Unit = {
        latch1.countDown()
        println("Completed fetching data")
      }

      override def onNext(movie: Document): Unit = {
        if (movie.get("movieId") != null) {
          ratingCollection.count(equal("movieId", movie.get("movieId"))).subscribe(new Observer[Long] {
            override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println(s"onError: $e")
            override def onNext(result: Long): Unit = { println(s"In count result : $result") }
            override def onComplete(): Unit = println("onComplete")
          })
        }
      }

    })
    latch1.await()
    mongoClient.close()
  }
```

I am using mongo 3.2.12 and scala -driver:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb.scala</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-scala-driver_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41852063/334862), and then add that codec to your codec registry. First, add

```
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromCodecs
```

You might already have other imports from that package already; for example, if you're using both providers, registries and codecs:

```
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.{fromRegistries, fromProviders, fromCodecs}
```

Just make sure you have everything you need imported.

Then:

```
val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(/* ..., */ fromCodecs(new SomeCodec()), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)

val mongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1")
val database = mongoClient.getDatabase("assignment").withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a little bit old, after losing many hours solving the same issue I write an update to it

Using Macros it's much easier now:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs._

  val movieCodecProvider: CodecProvider = Macros.createCodecProviderIgnoreNone[Movie]()
  val codecRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(movieCodecProvider), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)

  val movieCollection: MongoCollection[Movie] = mongo.database.withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry).getCollection("movie_collection")
```

pay attention when you write "manual" query (i.e. query in which you are not parsing an entire Movie object, like an update) you have to handle the Some field like a plain object

so to set it to None you do

```
movieCollection.updateOne(
              equal("_id", movie._id),
              unset("foo")
          )
```

to set it to Some

```
movieCollection.updateOne(
              equal("_id", movie._id),
              set("foo","some_value")
          )
```

Comment: This only works for `Option[T]` but not `A[Option[T]]`. Very frustrating to solve and I always forget why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure all fields are transformed into `Strings`. Especially enums, where you want the field to be inserted as `<your-enum>.map(_.toString)`.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer with some explanations, especially on why your proposal could be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The code that causes the exception is this

```scala
ratingCollection.count(equal("movieId", movie.get("movieId")))
```

Specifically `movie.get(...)` which has return type `Option[BsonValue]`. You cannot query collections with `Option[T]` values. Since you already checked against `null`, you could change the code to `movie.get("movieId").get` but the scala approach would be to utilize pattern matching, something akin to this.

```scala
override def onNext(movie: Document): Unit = {
  movie.get("movieId") match {
    case Some(movieId: BsonValue32) =>
      ratingCollection.count(equal("movieId", movieId)).subscribe(new Observer[Long] {
        override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println(s"onError: $e")
        override def onNext(result: Long): Unit = { println(s"In count result : $result") }
        override def onComplete(): Unit = println("onComplete")
      })
    case invalidId => 
      println(s"invalid id ${invalidId}")
  }
}
```

The underlying issue is how the mongo scala driver handles `Option[T]` monads. It's not well documented. [One of the answers already provided to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52585177/1507124) already shows how to solve this issue with querying case classes like `Foo(bar: Option[BsonValue])` but be aware that it fails for other case classes such as `Foo(bar: Seq[Option[BsonValue]])`.

As mentioned in the answer I refer to, the `createCodecProviderIgnoreNone` and related codec providers only applies to full document queries, like `insert`, `findReplace` etc. When doing field operation queries you have to unpack the `Option` yourself. I prefer to do this using pattern matching such as shown in my example.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me using the versions below:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
sbt.version = 1.3.8
```

```scala
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId

object Person {
  def apply(firstName: String, lastName: String): Person =
    Person(new ObjectId(), firstName, lastName)
}
case class Person(_id: ObjectId, firstName: String, lastName: String)
```

```scala
import models.Person
import org.mongodb.scala.{Completed, MongoClient, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase, Observer}
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.Macros._
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.{fromRegistries, fromProviders}

object PersonMain extends App {

  val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[Person]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb").withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
  val collection: MongoCollection[Person] = database.getCollection("people")

  def addDocument(doc: Person) = {
    collection.insertOne(doc)
      .subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {
        override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = println(s"Inserted $doc")
        override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println(s"Failed $e")
        override def onComplete(): Unit = println(s"Completed inserting $doc")
      })
  }

  addDocument(Person("name", "surname"))

  mongoClient.close()

}
```

Comment: you're not using any `Option[T]` monad

Comment: @CervEd could you re-work the example to use it then and show how to do it properly rather than just say it's bad.... not very helpful

Comment: There are no `Option[T]` monads in your code, there will be no `codec exception` related to using the `Option[T]` monad. See my answer for further explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/63282114/1507124